# Arrows in Table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix

is there a way to move the bolded bar to the left a little? (the one before the last 0). Also, could someone help me fix the slant of the last arrow to make it straight? Thanks! My code looks like this right now:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=0pt,
nodes={anchor=base east,inner xsep=6pt,inner ysep=6pt}] (M) {
& 1 & 5 & 4 & 20\\[-3pt]
-5 &   & -5 & -5  & -20\\[3pt]
& 1 & 0 & 4 & 0\\
};
\draw (M-2-1.south west) -- (M-2-6.south east);
\draw (M-1-2.north west) -- (M-3-2.south west);
\draw[line width=3pt] (M-2-6.south west) -- ++(0pt,-20pt);

\begin{scope}[->, shorten >=-4pt, shorten <=-4pt]
\draw (M-1-2) -- (M-3-2);
\draw (M-3-2) -- (M-2-3);
\draw (M-2-3) -- (M-3-3);
\draw (M-3-3) -- (M-2-4);
\draw (M-2-4) -- (M-3-4);
\draw (M-3-4) -- (M-2-5);
\draw (M-2-5) -- (M-3-5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. That code cannot work, your matrix has five columns, so `M-2-6` doesn't exist. Can you turn your snippet into a complete example that does work? (By complete, I mean add a `\documentclass` -- `article` is probably fine -- the necessary packages and tikzlibraries, and a `document` environment. That just makes it a little bit easier for those who want to help.)

Comment: This should be an edit to your previous question, not a new one. See also my answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

- first you need correct errors in your code snippet
- second, please always provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. help us to help you ... (is not fun write missing parts of your code, that we can test it)
- bar can be moved with `xshift{...}`
- nodes are not equal width, so you need to change start coordinates of perpendicular arrows

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=0pt,
        nodes={anchor=base east,inner sep=6pt}] (M) {
   & 1 & 5  & 4  &  20\\[-3pt]
-5 &   & -5 & -5 & -20\\[3pt]
   & 1 & 0  & 4  &   0\\
};
\draw (M-2-1.south west) -- (M-2-5.south east);
\draw (M-1-2.north west) -- (M-3-2.south west);
\draw[line width=3pt, semitransparent] ([xshift=-1mm] M-2-5.south west) -- ++(0pt,-20pt);

\begin{scope}[->, shorten >=-4pt, shorten <=-4pt]
\draw (M-1-2) -- (M-3-2);
\draw (M-3-2) -- (M-2-3);
\draw (M-2-3.south -| M-3-3) -- (M-3-3);
\draw (M-3-3) -- (M-2-4);
\draw (M-2-4.south -| M-3-4) -- (M-3-4);
\draw (M-3-4) -- (M-2-5);
\draw (M-2-5.south -| M-3-5) -- (M-3-5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```